# Android Studio: Check for a custom build type

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-build-type

I am trying to have a piece of code detect a BuildType, but I am a bit stuck.
Whenever I type the code in for the IF statement, it says

> Incompatible types.
>   Required: Boolean.
>   Found: java.lang.String

When I would have thought that it would have to be a string if there was .toString() at the end.

My code for detecting it is:

```
String buildtype = BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.toString();
if (buildtype = "admin") {
    //Do some admin stuff here.
}
```

I have set up the admin BuildType in my build.gradle file like this:

```
admin {
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable false
        renderscriptDebuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `=` is the _assignment_ operator, thats why it's telling you that you need a boolean and not a string, because you're assigning `buildtype` to `"admin"`, and not checking if `buildtype` _equals_ `"admin"`. To check for (reference) equality, use `==` instead. And, you should _not_ use `==` to compare Strings, though. Use `someString.equals(...)` for that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can look at your BuildConfig file. It is the file you will get after creating a build.

For your question. I think you should use `BuildConfig.FLAVOR` instead of `BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE`. And remember their type are `String`, so don't need to convert to String with `.toString()`

Lastly, you should use string compare method. So, your code should be

```
if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.contentEquals("admin")) {
    //Do some admin stuff here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This answered my question.

Comment: Quick question, would this be detecting productFlavors or BuildTypes. Thanks

Comment: It depend. Look at your `build.gradle` file. If `admin` is in `buildTypes` it will be dectected as BuildTypes
If `admin` is in `productFlavors` it will be dectected as Flavors.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much!

Comment: For me BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE return exactly the name of build. Where BuildConfig.FLAVOR returned an empty String

Comment: @PiVincii why did you use `contentEquals` instead of `equals`?

Answer (score 24):

What you can use in case you want to go for a custom build type and not a product flavor is:

```
if (BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.contentEquals("admin")) {
   // Do things related to the admin build type.
}
```

Comment: why did you use `contentEquals` instead of `equals`?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you've

```
android {

buildTypes {
    release {
    
    }
    debug {

    }
    canary {

    }
    beta {

    }
}
```

In code, you can check something like

```
import com.yourpackagename.BuildConfig

if (BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE == "canary") {
        Log.d("Build Type ","I'm canary")
    }
```